# Optimize UIBezierPath drawing

Tags: ios, core-graphics, drawrect, uibezierpath, quartz-core

I have a problem that I was hoping that someone in the community may have some expertise in. I am working on a drawing app. It's too much to get into as far as what it does and why, but at each touchesMoved:withEvent, a process of re-calculating an approximate bezier curve must take place and then redrawn. The approximation algorithm is such that, at any given moment a cubic curve can become quadratic and back. Therefore, the bounding box of the entire curve can change rather drastically point to point. 
    The naive approach is to simply take the bounds of the bezier curve and pass that to setNeedsDisplayInRect:, that's obviously much, much better than simply calling setNeedsDisplay, but when I profile the code, of course, a huge amount of time is spent inside drawRect. That comes with the problem, but I was hoping to reduce that.

Now, if the stroke call inside of UIBezierPath has sufficient overhead, it could render moot minimizing the volume of the rectangle that needs to be re-drawn. That could be the case, and simply using the naive approach becomes the best alternative. That's possibility #1.
     What I was hoping to try, however, was to create an algorithm that minimizes the aggregate volume of a set of rectangles that completely cover the bezier path. In other words, instead of calling setNeedsDisplayInRect once, calling it a few times. The union of the rects completely covers the UIBezierPath. I wish I could write this out more formally in LaTex or something, but I want to reduce the area I need to redraw with the caveat that the entire bezier path is a part of the union of these rects.
    Think dominoes. If I can choose from an infinite set of dominoes of every shape and size, how would I go about computing the set of dominoes that cover an arbitrary bezier path such that the volume of the dominoes is minimal.

Comment: Are you drawing a path containing a single curve segment (two endpoints and one or two control points)?  Or are you drawing a path containing many curve segments?

Comment: I doubt that you can improve performance that way. The overhead of `UIBezierPath` calculating which points need to be drawn is probably higher than filling the actual pixels (which should be pretty fast). It's even possible that performance would be worse because you'd have to draw the path multiple times, even if you'd fill fewer pixels overall.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, guys. I'm drawing one path with one or two control points. omz, that's sort of my concern. I have to figure out some optimizations to bring the CPU utilization down. It looks great but its pushing my iPad 4 to the edge. Not sure what it does to a 2 yet.